# How to make Kaggle understand the special characters ex; Arabic and Russian letters

Tags: r, encoding, kaggle

I am using a dataset that has all the videos of MrBeast and some videos and channels have a arabic and Russian letters how can I use change the encoding in Kaggle

https://www.kaggle.com/code/djouahdhia/mrbeast

I tried the Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE","arabic") but it is not working

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. BTW, your link is dead (404)…

Comment: Greetings! As the other user said, usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg